# Compare two csv file content and store the similar into variable

Tags: python, csv, compare

I am really new to python and I have two csv file. The first one (more.csv) has content of

```
A123,B456,C789
```

The second one (less.csv) has content of

```
B456
```

I want so that when they are the same they store the similar item into a variable called "same"

I figure it would start with something like:

```
more = open('more.csv','r')
less= open('less.csv','r')
for item in unitid:
```

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "when they are the same"? Do you mean when they both contain the same value such as both having B456?

Comment: are your csv files contain just one line each; if not, please, at least 2nd row to the examples

Comment: Yes, only one line each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they're only one line, you can use the *set* object (a python built-in) to compare them, for instance:

```
>>> a = ['A123','B456','C789','D007']
>>> b = ['B456','D007','E009']
>>> c = list(set(a).intersection(b))
>>> print c
['B456', 'D007']
```

The full method to compare from files would look like:

```
def compare( fileA, fileB ):
    a_file = open(fileA, 'r')
    a_data = a_file.read()
    a_file.close()

    b_file = open(fileB, 'r')
    b_data = b_file.read()
    b_file.close()

    # compare the contents
    a_set = set(a_data.split(','))
    b_set = set(b_data.split(','))

    return list(a_set.intersection(b_set))

compare('more.csv', 'less.csv')
```

If they are more than a single line per file, then you'd still be able to use this, you'd just have to modify it a bit - I guess storing the intersections into an array that represents the line-by-line similarities or something.

Answer (score 1):

Once you process your CSV files into lists you can use `collections.Counter` to find duplicates:

```
from collections import Counter

# after processing your CSV files into two lists:
more_list = ['A123', 'B456', 'C789', 'D007']
less_list = ['B456', 'D007', 'E009']

dupe_counter = Counter(more_list)
dupe_counter.update(less_list)
same_list = [val for val in dupe_counter if dupe_counter[val] > 1]
# same_list will be: ['B456', 'D007']
```

Comment: Is there a way not to use list but just csv.reader and for loop?